CSS width:auto behaviour with nested tables
I'm new to HTML but struggling with something that seems to me to be quite basic. I need to create some HTML to use as the basis for an e-mail template. As such due to the myriad considerations for e-mail clients with HTML rendering I'm using tables rather than grids etc. I am trying to ensure that nested tables in TD elements obey parent margins and padding but also occupy 100% of the available space in the TD. I'm attempting to use the width css attribute for this.
I have the following code as an exmaple to illustrate my issue:


<html>
<head>
<style>
    table{
        background-color: white;
    }

    td {
        background-color: rgb(179, 228, 247);
        border: 2px solid greenblack;
    }

    .emph{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .outer{
        background-color: rgb(210, 204, 208);
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .inner{
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: white;
    }


    .inner1{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .inner2{
        width:100%;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .inner3{    
        margin: 10px;
        width:auto;
    }

    .innerblock{    
       display:block;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="outer">
        <caption>Table 1</caption>
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td class="outer">    
                    <table class="inner inner1">
                        <caption>Nested Table 1</caption>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>If immediate parent table has <span class="emph">no</span> margin and width=100% then this TD <span class="emph">should not overlap </span> the containing TD element edge</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="outer">
                    <table class="inner inner2">
                        <caption>Nested Table 2</caption>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>If immediate parent table <span class="emph">has</span> a margin and width=100% then this TD might overlap the containing TD element edge as the 100% is the size of the parent table of this table without margins</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="outer">
                    <table class="inner inner3">
                        <caption>Nested Table 3</caption>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>If immediate parent table has width=auto then margins and padding <span class="emph">should be accounted for and no overlap</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="outer">
                    <table class="inner inner4 innerblock">
                    <caption>Nested Table 4</caption>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>If immediate parent table has width=auto then margins and padding <span class="emph">should be accounted for and no overlap</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>



So Nested Table 1 and Nested Table 2 are as expected based on use of width:100% but Nested Table 3 I want it to fill the parent TD space/horizontal width (you can see it's shrunk to the text size it seems). So I added display:block; to Nested Table 4 and this seems to work but why?

I changed my css as follows ans this seems ot have worked:
.inner3{
margin: 10px;
width:auto;
display:block;
}
I'm not sure why though?

The default display value for a table, is table. By setting it to block instead, you are removing some of the default behavior a table comes with.
